# VideoCapture() opencv python pyinstaller not opening

Tags: python, opencv, video

I am trying to produce an .exe of a simple GUI made with PyQt4 in python 2.7 using pyinstaller to play a video.

Here are the details of my problem:

Simple layout with two buttons, one to load video, other to play video. In my IDE, the video loads and plays perfectly. The video pops up in another window and closes when it is over.

After running pyinstaller on the program, the GUI interface pops up after running the .exe. The open file dialog works correctly, however the video will not play.

In my IDE I can reproduce the error by removing *opencv_ffmpeg2412_64.dll* from the opencv installation directory. Removing anything else in the directory does not seem to affect the playability of the video within the IDE. So I figure that pyinstaller is not finding opencv_ffmpeg2412_64.dll. I have tried to manually copy it into the dist folder produced by pyinstaller. I have also tried to hook it as well as include it in the specFile. I must be doing something wrong or looking in the wrong place to try and solve this issue.

Any ideas on how I could fix this would be much appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT:

Here is the main part of my code if it can be any help. This is only a test of a larger GUI that I am trying to place in an .exe file. I am using an older version of cv2 because of forwards compatibility problems.

```
#imports
import sys

from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4.QtGui import QFileDialog

import cv2
import numpy

import mainwindow


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, mainwindow.Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.Load_B.clicked.connect(self.open)
        self.Play_B.clicked.connect(self.play)

    def play(self):


        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(self.video)
        while(True):
            (grabbed, frame) = cap.read()
            if not grabbed:
                break            
            currentframe = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            height, width = currentframe.shape[:2]
            cv2.namedWindow("Preview", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL) 
            cv2.imshow("Preview",currentframe)  

            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break  
        cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()  

    def open(self):
        self.video=QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,"Video file",filter="Video 
    Files (*.mp4)")


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
app.aboutToQuit.connect(app.deleteLater)
form = MainWindow()
form.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Can you show us your code? Are you getting any errors (which ones)? Does the program crash or freeze or just not do what you want? Does the video load but not play or does nothing happen?

Comment: It does not crash, or freeze, however it does not show the video pop up that it does so nicely in my IDE. The video loads (I printed self.video to console) but then it does not play. I can also get into the play() function and print something before but not after the cv2.VideoCapture(self.video) statement. So it is not recognizing the function.

Comment: Your code looks fine. Did you use the `--add-binary` command on your spec file to point it to the dll?

Answer (score 5):

I just had this same problem and this worked for me:

Use the `--add-binary` option like BHawk pointed out to copy the dll from the `site-packages` folder to your dist folder when building the exe.

example:
`pyinstaller program.spec --add-binary <PATH_TO_PYTHON>\Lib\site-packages\cv2\opencv_ffmpeg320_64.dll;.`

Comment: In my case (May 2020 now), the file to look for was called opencv_videoio_ffmpeg420_64.dll

Answer (score 3):

Just as Garth5689 said, `--add-binary` worked well, and I'm on python 3.5. So this works on both python 2 and 3. In my example: `-F` = one file, `-w` = no cmd window.

```
pyinstaller -F -w yourpythonscript.py --add-binary C:\PATH\Python\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\cv2\opencv_videoio_ffmpeg411.dll;.
```