# imshow() opencv python pyinstaller not opening

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter

I am trying to edit an image which the user will provide and my opencv program will perform some steps on that image

I have created a gui for that in tkinter and then what i have done is make that tkinter gui into a executable file using pyinstaller

The tkinter part of the program works just fine but when the image is supposed to show using the imshow function it doesn't work

I have searched this problem in stack overflow and another user seems to have this problem but not like for imshowhe wants to show a video nd then that problem occured but in my case it is when imshow is called

[This is that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44415424/videocapture-opencv-python-pyinstaller-not-opening)

Now if i follow this answer they have said to enter the directory of: `C:\PATH\Python\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\cv2\opencv_videoio_ffmpeg411.dll;.` but when i go to site packages there is no cv folder instead there is opencv 4.4.0 and inside it there is not a file by .dll's

UPDATE

It does give me error and shows tkinter was not installed properly:

[image: This is the error]

How can i install tcl becuase i am making a exe from pyinstaller

Comment: Where is the [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Did you add `cv2.waitKey(0)` after `imshow`?

Comment: The code is too long and is divided into multiple files of python thats why i cant show it here. Also i have added the cv2.waitKey(0)

Comment: @Ahx Actullay it shows me some error the error is shown above on the question

Comment: Also i tried debugging and opencv works fine when i am not using tkinter but as soon as i want tkinter the window never opens and shows me this message

Answer (score 1):

A common problem I've experienced when using `cv.imshow` is that what you are passing to the function does not have the correct type. I suggest you checking what the type of the elements inside the numpy array is. For example if you are working with a B/W image you should cast the type into 'uint8'.

```
im.astype('uint8')
cv.imshow('Some window name', im)
```

Comment: i am using a colored image what should i type

Comment: I checked and this is also the type for color images. Could you paste the output of the error?

Comment: Try to debugg your code, add the line `import pbd` at the beggining of your file and the line `pdb.set_trace()` just after the line that you want to check is running